# facebook and socket.io node.js

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, express, socket.io

I have a some god idea, but I have some problems... how to connect facebook user to node app - socket.io

I was created an socket.io chat but now want to allow facebook users to come to chat to create something like facebook group CHAT. I think that idea is fine?

Here is my code for chat:

server side file - app.js

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

// rooms which are currently available in chat
var rooms = ['room1','room2','room3'];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // store the room name in the socket session for this client
        socket.room = 'room1';
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // send client to room 1
        socket.join('room1');
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to room1');
        // echo to room 1 that a person has connected to their room
        socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected to this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, 'room1');
    });

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
        // leave the current room (stored in session)
        socket.leave(socket.room);
        // join new room, received as function parameter
        socket.join(newroom);
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to '+ newroom);
        // sent message to OLD room
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has left this room');
        // update socket session room title
        socket.room = newroom;
        socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has joined this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});
```

and index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updaterooms', this updates the room the client is in
    socket.on('updaterooms', function(rooms, current_room) {
        $('#rooms').empty();
        $.each(rooms, function(key, value) {
            if(value == current_room){
                $('#rooms').append('<div>' + value + '</div>');
            }
            else {
                $('#rooms').append('<div><a href="#" onclick="switchRoom(\''+value+'\')">' + value + '</a></div>');
            }
        });
    });

    function switchRoom(room){
        socket.emit('switchRoom', room);
    }

    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
    <b>ROOMS</b>
    <div id="rooms"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
    <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
</div>
```

and how to allow users to come to chta with their facebook account via fbLogin button:

Here is fb login code, but HOW to implemet this code to my chat script to allow users to come with facebook accounts.

```
<button id="fb-auth">Login</button>

<script>
function updateButton(response) {
  Log.info('Updating Button', response);
  var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
    button.onclick = function() {
      FB.logout(function(response) {
        Log.info('FB.logout callback', response);
      });
    };
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = 'Login';
    button.onclick = function() {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        Log.info('FB.login callback', response);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          Log.info('User is logged in');
        } else {
          Log.info('User is logged out');
        }
      });
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: tryied in some ways but no working

Comment: *What* have you tried? You can't just dump a ton of unfinished code in here and expect everyone else to finish it for you. Be more specific about *what* you've tried and *what* is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing in my app Snakes-n-Ladders multiplayer (https://apps.facebook.com/snakes-n-ladders/). You need to authenticate user at server to.

Library I am using : facebook-node-sdk.

You need to put cookie : true while initializing JavaScript SDK. So that the user authenticated at client will be authenticate at server.

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
});
```

Read the documentation for facebook-node-sdk, you will all user info at server. You can attach data to a socket session.

Answer (score -1):

I have done something similar to this:**http://codemygenes.appspot.com/nodejs/fbchat/fbchat.html**. But its too complicated to understand. I have deployed a socket.io chat(node.js App) on Heroku. Also I have used Facebook authentication. For that I have followed below points:

1. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/. And they have a neat document about Graph API.
2. You have to deploy the app on server(like Heroku or even you localhost!).
3. Register App on facebook. http://developers.facebook.com/apps
4. Facebook will give ur app an ID & Client_secret code. And you have to authenticate the app every time with that ID & Secret code.

Briefly, Go to facebook graph API documentations and you have all there...

View demo [here](https://sharp-window-7156.herokuapp.com/login)